# Filling the values of matrix in r using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix or data frame where each row of the matrix will fill by the result of each loop. The fact is the number of values we get on each loop are not same. So how can I do it where we will first fill the columns values with the loop result and the rest of the unfilled values on a row/rows will be null. My r code is

```
x<-c(9,10,6,17,23,16,27,18,8,11)
K<-7
ash<-matrix(, nrow = K, ncol = max(x))
for (i in 1:K){
  aa<-max.col(theta, ties.method="first")==i
  ash[i,]<-which(aa==TRUE)
}
```

A example is

```
a1<-c(1,4,5,7)
> a2<-c(3,6,12,3,45)
> a3<-c(5,9,12,14,3,9,7,2)
> main<-matrix(c(1,4,5,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,6,12,3,45,NA,NA,NA,5,9,12,14,3,9,7,2),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE)
> main
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    4    5    7   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    3    6   12    3   45   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    9   12   14    3    9    7    2
```

The desired matrix should look like main matrix, and a1, a2, a3 are the results of each loops. Couldn't figure out how can I give you an exactly producible output as I created the example "main" manually.

Comment: @akrun, theta is parameter vector. And  aa<-max.col(theta, ties.method="first")==i give us basically true false vector. The code you provided does not work. It gives error Error ```in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, i1, value = c(9L, 10L, 66L, 67L,  : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns```

Comment: @akrun edited the question.

Comment: @akrun it's hard to explain the theta value, Theta is basically matrix of K rows and the number of columns is the total number of values we get from all loops combined. Each elements of the theta is a decimal point(probability). For like example I gave  (a1, a2, a3 ) theta is 3 by 17. Because length(a1)+length(a2)+length(a3)=17. Let me know if it's still confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be changed to

```
for (i in 1:K){
  aa<-max.col(theta, ties.method="first")==i
   i1 <- which(aa)
  ash[i,i1] <- i1
}
```

#### Update

Based on the 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'

```
lst1 <- list(a1, a2, a3)
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

-output

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    4    5    7   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    3    6   12    3   45   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    9   12   14    3    9    7    2
```